# contractAddress: null

Tags: web3js

I use sendSignedTransaction to send the contract and return contractAddress: null

```
      let rpcUrl = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/6756e6f8f0e34482a262a7cf1d15f2c2";
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));
  var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'HelloWorld.sol': {
        content: 'pragma solidity ^0.5.10; contract HelloWorld { function f() public { } }'
      }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['*']
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var compiled = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))
  var output = JSON.parse(compiled);
  var bytecode = output.contracts["HelloWorld.sol"]['HelloWorld'].evm.bytecode.object
  const privateKey = Buffer.from(
    'my privatekey',
    'hex'
  )

  web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0x146DD8c053d94354C75783Ff8846012C8907Df17").then(function (transactionCount) {
    console.log(web3.utils.toHex(transactionCount));
    var txParams = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionCount),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(1000),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
      to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      value: '0x00',
      data: "0x" + bytecode,
    }
    const tx = new Tx(txParams, { 'chain': 'ropsten' })
    tx.sign(privateKey)
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize()

    var receipt=null;

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(hash);
      while (receipt == null) {

        receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);

      }

      console.log('Contract address: ' + receipt.contractAddress);





  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ blockHash:
```

'0x6a77b44ca49bd3a822d7a033251cc425941c6a184b555c3242831f4180ff7ebf',
  blockNumber: 6183868,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 5492997,
  from: '0x146dd8c053d94354c75783ff8846012c8907df17',
  gasUsed: 29740,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom:
   '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  transactionHash:
   '0x44adb75d7ee2d0fa0ba939784354f9b0fe512887d988711296995973c20be4a1',
  transactionIndex: 12 }

Comment: Please edit your own question if you want to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You send the transaction to the "zero" address "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", which itself is a valid address. For ethereum it looks like a transfer of ether.

To create a contract you have to send it to the "null" address, removing "to" in the txParams should be enough.

```
var txParams = {
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionCount),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(1000),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
  // to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', <--- removed
  value: '0x00',
  data: "0x" + bytecode,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've settled it.